# Azure Repos not an option in Deployment Center of Azure Web App

Tags: azure, azure-devops, continuous-deployment, azure-webapps

I am trying to deploy code as an Azure Web App. The code is in an Azure DevOps Repo. However, Azure Repos is not listed as an option in the Deployment Center.

How can I make *Azure Repos* visible under *Source* in the *Deployment Center* as mentioned in the documentation? See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/app-service/deploy-continuous-deployment?tabs=repos)

[image]

Comment: Have you created a service connection from DevOps to your subscription? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/connect-to-azure?view=azure-devops

Comment: I've always set up deployment by creating a DevOps pipeline, never touched the Deployment Center. That may get you better results. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/targets/webapp?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic

Comment: It seems that Azure Repos is only available for Windows Apps. Windows Apps, however, are not available for Python runtime stacks (only Linux Apps). So, as Noah said, in my case DevOps pipeline seems to be the way to go.